# Looking to rewrite a url with a hash using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, hash, url-rewriting

I have a url with the format `http://www.site.com/index.php/page` and want to rewrite it to `http://www.site.com/#/page` but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to replace `index.php` with `#` you can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule   ^/index.php/(.*)    /#/$1  [NE,R]
```

The NE flag should keep mod_rewrite from escaping the `#`

Comment: You need to remove the leading `/` when using this rule in the .htaccess context. So `RewriteRule   ^/index.php/(.*)    /#/$1  [NE,R]`. Thanks M_M for showing a use-case for NE. Very educational.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I can't get it working. I have other RewriteRules and they all work fine, so it shouldn't be a problem with the file. Here is the full code.  `AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?  
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)  
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^/index.php/(.*) /#/$1 [NE,R]`